# Forcing people to open a webpage in Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript

Can I force users who click on a webpage in Firefox/Safari to open it in Chrome or IE with javascript? Assuming they have those browsers downloaded.

Comment: your 2nd question is off-topic, and the 2 are totally unrelated to each other...

Comment: Best thing you can do is showing a message. But why would you only want users that uses chrome or IE in the first place?

Comment: what alert message are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. How would you expect a client without Chrome or IE installed (and these would certainly not be a small proportion) to open the webpage in either of those browsers?

You *could* check the HTTP headers for the user-agent string which would give you the clients browser, and decide not to give them the content of the page based on this.

**EDIT:** The following code establishes which browser the client is using and decides what to do based on this information.

```
<? php
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if !(preg_match($user_agent, '/Firefox/i')) {
        include ('page.php');
        }
?>
```

This example should get you started. Also look into PHP's [get_browser()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function.

Comment: Would you be willing to elaborate on that second option, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if those other browsers are present on the user's system. It is their choice which browser they use.

Even popping up a message advising that the site works better in browser x is a pretty poor experience for the user and pretty bad form for a developer.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't planning on doing that thanks though. But by chance do you know where I can find a free web hosting service with SSL support.

Comment: Off the top of my head no, but it's kind of an open question. What platform is the site built on (i.e. PHP or .Net? how much bandwidth you need? How much storage space? Mail accounts? Use Google and narrow down based on what else you need. once you found some that are suitable by all means ask for further advice :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+

if(isSafari || isFirefox) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "";
    alert("No content for you, unless you use Chrome or IE!");
}
```

Comment: so it just gives them no content if they open it in safari or firefox

Comment: Ya, isn't that what you wanted?